# Formating output of a linux command

Tags: java, linux, jsp, unix

I am developing a web application.By using this I want to execute a command in remote machine LINUX machine.Now my Requirement is that I want to display the output of the command in my webpage(JSP page). Is there any java API to simplify the parsing of the output?

Comment: How should the data be formatted differently between how it appears in the CLI on the Linux machine, and how it should appear in a web page?

Comment: @Andrew : I would like to display it an table format.

Comment: And how is that ***different*** to how it is displayed in a command line?  Pretend I'm ***not*** sitting in front of your machine, and ***not*** psychic.  Copy/paste some typical output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not familiar with JSP. But if you are developing web applications, you must be using HTML/CSS. Have the output of Linux command store in a variable. Then you are done with the Linux command. Now move to JAVA for parsing. I am sure that there are great modules available for parsing. Then after that format the output using HTML, CSS.